# How to choose Private Key Alias in iOS similar to Android?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I choose manually Trusted CA Certificate in iOS like in Android KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(this, this, new String[]{"RSA"}, null, null, -1, null); for making Secure TLS connection.

Comment: How to prompt certificate to choose?

Comment: How can I choose manually Trusted CA Certificate in Xcode (Swift) iOS like in Android KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(this, this, new String[]{"RSA"}, null, null, -1, null); for making Secure TLS connection